# Как читается запись ∃x~(Ɐy)R(x,y)?

Tags: математика, дискретная-математика

вот есть запись:
∃x~(Ɐy)R(x,y),

где R(x,y) - предикат

как эта запись читаеться?

есть некоторое x, и не каждое y что высказывание: R(x,y) истинно?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Читается это так: "существует такое х, что не для каждого y истинно/выполняется R(x,y)".

Это эквивалентно тому, что "существует такое х, что для него существует y, для которых не выполняется R(x,y)".